# Windsor and ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem: "HttpContext.Current is null. PerWebRequestLifestyle can only be used in ASP.Net"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, multithreading, asp.net-mvc-3, castle-windsor, threadpool

I am trying to enhance the in proc MVC cache to serve the old value while triggering a new thread to populate the new value.

This below code "works" if I remove the line:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate
```

By "works" I mean that the client that made the request that triggered the cache reload is blocked until the cache is refreshed, but all other clients continue to load against the shadow version.

Ideally, I want the processing to occur in the background and the client that triggered the cache refresh to use the shadow copy for that request. When they make a future request  once the thread has completed they would be served the new cached values.

My solution relies heavily on Castle as the DI framework. I believe the problem I am getting is to do with LifeStyles in Castle. The error message is:

**HttpContext.Current is null. PerWebRequestLifestyle can only be used in ASP.Net**

The exception happens deep in the bowels of the long running process (*getCacheItem()*) when it is trying to resolve a component that is required.

My cache method is as follows:

```
public T GetShadow<T>(string key, Func<T> getCacheItem, int timeOut)
{
    if (Exists(key))
    {
        _log.Info("Shadow: Returning item from Cache: " + key);
        return (T)HttpContext.Current.Cache[key];
    }

    var shadowKey = key + "-shadow";

    if (Monitor.TryEnter(GetKeyLock(key)))
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate
        {
            try
            {
                var item = getCacheItem(); // Long running query

                // Replace the cache entry
                HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(key, item, null,
                                    DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(
                                           timeOut), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);

                // And add its shadow for subsequent updates
                HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(shadowKey, item, null,
                                    DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(timeOut * 2), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
            }
            finally
            {
                Monitor.Exit(GetKeyLock(key));
            }
        });
    }

    while (!Exists(shadowKey))
    {
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }

    return (T)HttpContext.Current.Cache[shadowKey];
}
```

So my question is, am I doing the thread creation correctly within MVC3??

Is there a better way to spin up a thread in this scenario that will not cause Windsor to throw an exception due to the PWR lifestyle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So my question is, am I doing the thread creation correctly within MVC3??

No, you are using `HttpContext.Current` inside a background thread in an ASP.NET application. Your problem has nothing to do with Windsor nor ASP.NET MVC. It's just something that you can't do simply because background threads (as their name suggests) could run in the background outside from any user HTTP context. So attempting to access this context inside such a thread doesn't make any sense.

You could use the new caching features in .NET 4.0 thanks to the new [MemoryCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.aspx) class which was designed to be used independently of ASP.NET.